# How to set folder properties in Win 10?

Tags: windows-10, user-folders

Procedure I have been told works.
1. Open an explorer folder and set the options to the way you want them.
2. Go to File Explorer Options > View.
3. Apply to folders.

I have tried this so many times and always the button is greyed out and I cannot select it. I have to constantly change the way they look.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got it a bit incorrectly. The correct steps are:

1. Open the folder
2. Go to file explorer options -> view
3. Make the changes in the dialog - see below
4. Apply to All folders

That should work

[image]